# Hough Transform parameters using EmguCV

Tags: c#, image-processing, hough-transform, emgucv

I am working with application that i use Hough Transform, and i want to reduce multiple lines with similar parameter, but i don't know where i can find rho and theta from Hough accumulator.

This is my implementation of Hough

```
LineSegment2D[] lines = CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(cannyEdges, 1, Math.PI / 180.0, 12, 1, 7);

        foreach (LineSegment2D line in lines)
         image_PB2.Draw(line, new Bgr(Color.Green), 1);
        pictureBox2.Image = image_PB2.Bitmap;
```

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/2966/how-do-the-rho-and-theta-values-work-in-houghlines/

Comment: If I code like in this example i have error: 
Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'LineSegment2D' with float rho = lines[i][0];

Comment: That link was just to explain the concept :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175203/detected-lines-angle-in-emgucv . This link shows you how to convert from cartesian to polar coordinates in emgu.

Comment: You might also want to look into http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/48504695-f191-e805-fb22-6ed454bc4b21.htm

Comment: Ok, so i can't get this parameters directly from hough transform in emgu?

Comment: You can probably get it from the LineSegment2D (lines[i]). Something like lines[i].Direction, but you have to figure out what it means, the docs are not quite clear. It might be radians, degrees or some normalized value)

Comment: https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/blob/5996ec82b5666005d379b7e5d8ca43f72c1de137/Emgu.CV/PointAndLine/LineSegment2D.cs#L37-L48  So this will not help, as it simply gets a "vector"/segment of norm 1 with the same direction as the line